Irreversible uncharged acid/base indicator
I am conducting a process in an electrochemical cell where at the cathode or anode surface the pH might be acidic or basic. To figure out if either one is correct I would like to find a reaction that is catalyzed by hydroxide (but not protons or vice versa) that I could flow through the catholyte/anolyte. At the outlet I would then collect the liquid and measure if I formed any product which is why it needs to form irreversibly because the outlet will be at a different pH. It is very important that this indicator molecule and its product is not charged as I do not want to change anything about the ionic conductivity. As a separator I can use a proton exchange membrane or an anion exchange membrane (AEM), in the case I use an AEM I could also use a acid catalyzed reaction since the membrane wouldn't be able catalyze the reaction. In either case I need the indicator and product to be at least a bit electrochemically stable as the cell potential I am applying could go up to 3V (likely my cathode will be at -1V vs SHE and my anode at 2V vs SHE).
I have scoured the internet/literature but I am unable to find a reaction that fulfils my requirements which is why I am asking it here. I know my question might sound vague so if you need any additional information let me know!
